DriveApp.MakeCopy TypeError: imgname.makeCopy is not a function copyFilesFromSpreadsheet @ Code.gs:35
I get this error:

TypeError: imgname.makeCopy is not a function copyFilesFromSpreadsheet @ Code.gs:35

I have searched the internet and read all the other posts about Makecopy to no avail. I'm a beginner in App Scripts in Google Drive. My gut is telling me that I don't have access to the DriveApp service... but I think I enabled it. See under services on the left.

OR that the script doesn't know where to look for it in MY Drive. SourceFolderID is never referenced, so it might not know where to find it? So how do I reference locations in App Scripts?  You can see from the debug window that the first iteration of the variables from the spreadsheet are getting lifted from the spreadsheet properly. So I know that's doing ok.
Much appreciated for any guidance.
I tried moving the files out of a shared drive into my drive thinking maybe it was a permissions issue. My test playground currently has the spreadsheet sitting on the root level of the source folder.
I believe I have enabled the Drive service and the Spreadsheet service which I THINK holds the class Makecopy. I can't tell from the error if Makecopy is returning null because it doesn't recognize the file name or the location.
I believe I may be lost in google land and not understanding where things are held?
   function copyFilesFromSpreadsheet() {

  // Get spreadsheet data

  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("testmove"); // Replace with your sheet name

  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();



  // Loop through each row

  for (var i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {

   
    
    var fileName = data[i][1]; // Assuming file name is in the first column

    var sourceFolderId = data[i][0]; // Assuming source folder ID is in the second column

    var destFolderId = data[i][2]; // Assuming destination folder ID is in the third column

   

    // Find file in Drive
    var files = DriveApp.getFiles();
    var imgname = DriveApp.getFilesByName(fileName);
    
    if (imgname) {

      // Copy file to destination folder

      imgname.makeCopy(imgname, DriveApp.getFolderById(destFolderId));
      
    }

  }

}


imgName is a iterator. It is not a  File

As written in the documentation, getFilesByName returns a FileIterator.
var imgname = DriveApp.getFilesByName(fileName);

imgName is of type FileIterator, which doesn't have .makeCopy method. FileIterator has these methods. To get the file from it's iterator, use next method:
const imgnameFileIterator = DriveApp.getFilesByName(fileName);
if (imgnameFileIterator.hasNext()) {
   // Copy file to destination folder
   imgnameFileIterator.next().makeCopy(imgname, DriveApp.getFolderById(destFolderId));      
}

